# Warning: Undefined variable

Tags: array, string, undefined, php8, int

Tengo esta clase en la cual se le asignan al arregloUnidadMedicones las variables id (int) y descr (varchar)

```
function listar() {
        $comandoSql = "SELECT * FROM unidad_de_medicion";
        $objControlConexion = new ControlConexion();
        $objControlConexion->abrirBd($GLOBALS['serv'],$GLOBALS['usua'],$GLOBALS['pass'],$GLOBALS['bdat'],$GLOBALS['port']);
        $recordSet = $objControlConexion->ejecutarSelect($comandoSql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($recordSet) > 0) {
             $arregloUnidadMediciones = array();
            $i=0;
            while($row = $recordSet->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
                $objUnidadMedicion=new Unidad_Medicion("","");
                $objUnidadMedicion->setId($row['id']);
                $objUnidadMedicion->setDescripcion($row['descr']);
                $arregloUnidadMediciones[$i]=$objUnidadMedicion;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        $objControlConexion->cerrarBd();
        return $arregloUnidadMediciones;
    }
```

me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] ,

**Pero cuando ambas variables son varchar no presenta error**

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar el código en vez de una imagen? Así se nos hará más fácil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Sofia, bienvenida, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo tu código (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y los errores en formato texto, así tu pregunta será mejor recibida, y evitarás recibir votos negativos, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: Si esto no se cumple: `if (mysqli_num_rows($recordSet) > 0)`, entonces `$arregloUnidadMediciones` no estará definido, y abajo se está haciendo `return` a una variable no definida. Dos opciones: (1) Coloca `$arregloUnidadMediciones = array();` fuera del `if`, o sea, en la línea anterior al `if`. (2), Coloca un `else` para darle un valor a esa variable si no logró entrar al `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. La variable no está definida para todos los ámbitos, de modo que si el `if` no se cumple la variable no existirá. Ese es el motivo del error actual. Pero hay más cosas ...
2. No necesitas usar `mysqli_num_rows()` para saber si hay filas, de hecho, en algunos escenarios esta llamada no te garantizará tal comprobación. Es mejor verificar los datos en sí mismos como veremos en la solución propuesta.
3. No necesitas llevar un contador (`$i`) para ir llenando el eventual array con los datos.
4. No necesitas usar `MYSQLI_BOTH` el cual organiza los datos de dos formas, como array asociativo y como array numérico, basta con tenerlos como array asociativo, todo lo demás es desperdiciar memoria.

Propongo esta solución aplicando todas las mejoras señaladas más arriba:

```
function listar() {
    /*
      Al declararla aquí, la variable estará en
      todo el ámbito de la función
      */
    $arregloUnidadMediciones = array();
    $comandoSql = "SELECT * FROM unidad_de_medicion";
    $objControlConexion = new ControlConexion();
    $objControlConexion->abrirBd($GLOBALS['serv'],$GLOBALS['usua'],$GLOBALS['pass'],$GLOBALS['bdat'],$GLOBALS['port']);
    $recordSet = $objControlConexion->ejecutarSelect($comandoSql);
    while($row = $recordSet->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $objUnidadMedicion=new Unidad_Medicion("","");
        $objUnidadMedicion->setId($row['id']);
        $objUnidadMedicion->setDescripcion($row['descr']);
        $arregloUnidadMediciones[]=$objUnidadMedicion;
    }
    $objControlConexion->cerrarBd();
    /*
      Si no hay datos, $arregloUnidadMediciones será false
      esto sustituye a mysqli_num_rows()
      y permite una verificación más segura
      basada en los mismos datos
      */
    if (!$arregloUnidadMediciones) {
       $arregloUnidadMediciones['error']='No hay datos';
    }
    return $arregloUnidadMediciones;
}
```

Donde recibes la respuesta, `$arregloUnidadMediciones` tendrá los datos, o una clave `error` describiendo que no hay datos, esto es útil si quieres (deberías) contemplar manejo de errores en tu código.

Otra cosa es que si el constructor de `Unidad_Medicion` recibe en parámetro los datos luego pasas en los dos *setter*, los puedes obviar, pasando los datos al constructor, algo así:

```
$objUnidadMedicion=new Unidad_Medicion($row['id'],$row['descr']);
```

Pero no veo tu clase, para saber qué recibe el constructor de la misma.